# return a value from a javascript callback

Tags: javascript

I need to pass a value to a function, which contains a modifier method, and then `return` the modified value.

What's the best way to do this?

I have a `read` function (which parses content) and a `scan` function (which looks for a word in the content.

I have the following code so far:

```
scanContent = function(url){
  read(url, function(err, article, meta) {

      var content = article.title + article.content

      return scan(content)

    }
    return scan(content)
  });

  return scan(content)

}
```

This obviously doesn't work, but I'm not really sure what the right approach is here.

Comment: That's because `byThree` function get only 1 argument.

Comment: Why do you need a callback for that?

Comment: Uh why don't you just use console.log('result: ' + byThree(5) );

Comment: I probably haven't constructed the example very well, but I'm basically trying to work out how to pass values through the return function.

Comment: Please show your *real* code. The example is too simplistic to grasp the actual problem.

Comment: Ok, will edit the question with the real code and more context.

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide callback function parameter and call it with your result:

```
function byThree(n, callback) {
    var x = n * 3;
    callback(x);
}
var multiply = function(n, callback) {
    byThree(n, function(result) {
        callback(result);
    });
};

multiply(5, function(result) {
    console.log('result: ' + result);
});
```

Comment: The anonymous function should have a `x` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
function byThree(n){
    return n * 3;
}
multiply = function(n){
    return byThree(n);
};
console.log("result: "+multiply(5));
```

Though the following makes more sense:

```
function multiply(n, m){
    return n * m;
};
console.log("result: "+multiply(5, 3));
```

And the following makes even more sense:

```
console.log("result: " + 5 * 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

If function gets a meaningful result from an inner callback, then it can return a meaningful result only by another callback. You can't trick the program flow.

So, it would be like that:

```
var scanContent = function(url, cb){
  read(url, function(err, article, meta) {
      var content = article.title + article.content

      return cb(scan(content)); // asume 'scan' is defined elsewhere
    }
  });
};

scanContent(function(text) { console.log(text); });
```

This could lead to the [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/). There is [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise2=EXGAJnquvIKgieh5BF6EaQ) from ES6 to avoid that. And [generators](http://www.2ality.com/2015/03/no-promises.html) to make the code even more straightforward.

With Promises (and arrow functions):

```
var scanContent = function(url){
  // simplified; it's better to always return a promise in the real code
  return read(url).then((err, article) => scan(article.title + article.content));
};

scanContent('example.com').then((text) => console.log(text));
```